# i don't know what to change about this code. does anyone know why it keeps giving me the same TypeError i tried it with/without str() and use return

Tags: python-3.x, list, oop, append, typeerror

this is the error that i keep getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\baris\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 60, in 
print(my_hand)
TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

this is the complete code but the problem i run in to is that it doesn't add anything to my_hand. does anyone know why?:

```
class Card(object):
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["D", "S", "H", "C"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return str(rep)


class Hand(object):
    """a hand of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "  "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
            return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)


card1 = Card(rank="A", suit="c")
print(card1)
card2 = Card(rank="2", suit="c")
card3 = Card(rank="3", suit="c")
card4 = Card(rank="4", suit="c")
card5 = Card(rank="5", suit="c")
print(card2)
print(card3)
print(card4)
print(card5)

my_hand = Hand()
print("my hand before i add cards\n", my_hand)
my_hand.add(card1)
my_hand.add(card2)
my_hand.add(card3)
my_hand.add(card4)
my_hand.add(card5)
print("my hand after adding 5 cards: ")
print(my_hand)

your_hand = Hand()
my_hand.give(card1, your_hand)
my_hand.give(card2, your_hand)
print("your hand: ")
print(your_hand)
print("my hand: ")
print(my_hand)

my_hand.clear()
print("my hand now: ")
print(my_hand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__str__` function of `Hand`, you aren't returning `rep` when `self.cards` has anything, so the code just falls through to the end of the function. Adding `return rep` after the loop should fix it.